# $P(x)=e^x$ has a finite number of solutions .

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P$ be a polynomial function , then we need to show that the equation :

$P(x)=e^x$ cannot have infinitely many solutions .

I thought about the nth-derivative of   $g(x)=P(x)-e^x$ ,   if there are infinitely many solutions then $g$ takes the value $0$ more than $n=deg(P)+1$ times . Thus the n-th derivative of  $g$ vanishes at some point , which is absurd  . Because the n-th derivative of $g$ is $e^x$.

*(My intuition tells me that there can be a proof using the variation of $P$ and $exp$)* is there any idea to solve it besides the idea of the n-th derivative ?

Comment: If $P(x)=1$, identically, then $e^x=1$ has infinitely many solutions.  Or did you mean to specify real solutions?

Comment: Why do you think it has a finite number of solutions, when $\sum_{0}^\infty e^x=\frac{1}{n!}x^n$?

Comment: If you meant real, then note that between each two roots of $P(x)-e^x$ there must be a root of $P'(x)-e^x$, so you can work inductively.

Comment: The function $g(x)=P(x)-e^x$ is analytic and non-constant, so its roots are isolated. To conclude, you have to show that for $|x|$ large enough, $g$ has no root. For this, use that for such $x$ you have $|P(x)|\sim C|x|^{\mathrm{deg}(P)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution would be to first note that, the set of solutions must be bounded.

This is because for some $M_1$, you have $e^x>P(x)$ for all $x>0$, and some $M_2$ such that $P(x)>1$ for $x<M_2$ (because the limit of $P$, as $x\to-\infty$, is $\pm \infty$.

Because the set of solutions is bounded, it must have a convergence point. This is not possible because the function $g(x)=P(x)-e^x$ is analytic and non-constant, and the roots of such function are always isolated.